# Does $\sum \limits _{k=1}^\infty \frac{3n+2}{n(n+1)}$ converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does $\sum \limits _{k=1}^\infty \frac{3n+2}{n(n+1)}$ converges?

Well, I know that $\frac{3n+2}{n(n+1)} = \frac{3}{(n+1)} + \frac{2}{n(n+1)}$

and I know that $\sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty \frac{3}{(n+1)}$ < 3 and $\sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{n(n+1)}$ < 2 Which implies that (with arithmetic limits) that $\sum \limits _{k=1}^\infty \frac{3n+2}{n(n+1)}$ converges. Is that true? (In the book answers, it says that this series isn't converging, because it says that it converges to $\infty$ because $\sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty \frac{3}{(n+1)}$ converges to $\infty$ and the second one too, because it is always positive, which doesn't make sense with the solution I came up with.)

Comment: The series converges. It can be proved by ratio test.

Comment: $\frac{3n+2}{n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{2}{n}$

Comment: It is not true that $\sum_1^\infty \frac{3}{n+1}\lt 3$.  The series on the left diverges.

Comment: The series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{3}{n+1}$ diverges to $+\infty$. This behaves exactly as the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29).

Comment: @SuryaPrakash No, the ratio test is inconclusive.

Comment: "I know sum 3/(n+1) < 3".  No you don't.  sum 3/n+1 = 3 (sum 1/n) - 1 and unfortunately,  sum 1/n $\ge$ 4/3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have
$$
\frac{3n+2}{n(n+1)}>\frac{3n}{n(n+1)}>\frac{1}{n+1} \quad \qquad n=1,2,\cdots,
$$ thus your initial series is **divergent** as is the harmonic series.

Comment: can I take a conclusion from you answer? if I take any series, and I always make the series smaller and smaller like you did, it will be easier to show divergence. but if I take a series and I make that series bigger than the given series, then It'll be easier to prove convergence?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS I understand what you mean, but let me tell you that there is no **general** rule. Here things work because $u_n \sim \dfrac{3}{n}$ and the latter is the general term of a divergent series. Thank you!

Comment: if in the denominator it was $n^2(n+1)$ then it would converge right? because for $p > 1$ in sum to infinity of $\frac{1}{n^p}$ will always converge. right?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS Right.

Answer (score 2):

Your statement: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{3}{n+1} < 3$  is incorrect as the LHS goes to infitiny.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{3n+2}{n(n+1)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg (\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{2}{n} \bigg) >\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{n}$$
which means your series is divergent.

Answer (score 1):

It is obviously diverging, since the general term behaves like $\frac{3}{n}$.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{3n+2}{n(n+1)}=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\geq 3H_N-1\geq 3\log N. $$

Answer (score 1):

As it is a series with positive terms, equivalence* is enough:
$$\frac{3n+2}{n(n+1)}\sim_\infty\frac{3n}{n^2}=\frac3n,$$
which diverges

Answer (score 0):

Say, $u_n=\frac{3n+2}{n(n+1)}$ and $v_n=\frac{1}{n}$

By comparison test, $$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac{u_n}{v_n}=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{3n+2}{n(n+1)}}{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac{3+\frac{2}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{n}}=3(\not =0,\infty)$$

And $\sum v_n$ is divergent.

So $\sum u_n$ is divergent.